# In Java: How to handshake a secured connection using Keystore and Truststore certificate?

Tags: java, security, keystore, truststore

If I have 2 terminals A and B. T-A is connect T-B over secured socket connection. I need to write code to implement a connection between the 2 terminals.

How do I do handshake such connection using Keystore and Truststore. Another word, where do I place keystore/truststore certificate file? (T-A or T-B)

Any good advice or good example is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a PDF whitepaper entitled [Using JSSE for secure socket communication](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/j-jsse/j-jsse-ltr.pdf) which may help answer your question, including configuration of your keystore files.